# Are there any concerns with newer versions of eclipse (indigo) and netbeans (7.0) being on the same pc?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide

I've done some searches and see **IN THE PAST** there have not been any issues with eclipse and netbeans being on the same machine.  However, I haven't seen anything regarding this issue with the newer versions of eclipse and netbeans.  I don't like to assume it's still okay now because it was a few years ago.

Anyone have personal experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had no problems with the two coexisting. They live in their own separate folders, and don't seem to get out much. I give Eclipse more attention though, as it's my favorite. Netbeans' jealousy has never manifested.

Comment: I like eclipse, but we are wanting to have Netbeans for it's swing building functionality and a lot of the tutorials on Oracle/Sun are for that IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Really what could be a reason for some conflict ?  These tools are well-behaving applications, not some DLL-nightmare beasts.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but because of the work environment I have to get every ide, plugin, jar, tool, etc... that want to work with approved.  I have to do my due diligence and not assume anything.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add my experience with Eclipse and NetBeans IDE which may be useful for decision making.

We have used Eclipse and NetBeans simultaneously since last 4 years, we develop code in Eclipse but design Forms and Panels in NetBeans, and we have never had any issue running them side by side.

I am still running Eclipse Indigo and NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 as well as NetBeans IDE 7.1 Beta and all are running well in same MacBook.